# python Requests substitute for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web-scraping

I am trying to login to nike.com with only requests module, and the post url is

```
https://unite.nike.com/login?appVersion=369&experienceVersion=312&uxid=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web&locale=en_US&backendEnvironment=identity&browser=Google%20Inc.&os=undefined&mobile=false&native=false&visit=3&visitor=e3c617a5-8ca4-435c-88b3-d717be116f5f'
```

Notice how at the end there's a long string of some sort of user-id. I'm able to acquire this string with selenium by accessing local storage. 
Now my question is, how do I use only the requests module and javascript deciphering to get this string? I know this is difficult, but I would like to at least where I should start looking.

Thank you!

Comment: Guess you don't need to search or construct the id to create target link.  Instead, you can back a step which uses selenium to post login action (with your password and username) message in the login form.  And then navigate to the page you need.

Comment: Are you saying that, when visiting a particular page, the page writes a string to the browser’s local storage, and that you want to extract that string from local storage without actually running a browser?

Comment: yes @Ian that is my question. I'm asking because I want this process to be as fast as possible. Maybe I should use a headless browser like phantomJS?

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is, how do I use only the requests module and javascript deciphering to get this string [from local storage]?

In short, you can't.

Local storage is a browser feature exposed via JavaScript. To access it, you will need to use a browser with a JavaScript runtime, e.g., Chrome running in headless mode, PhantomJS, etc.